# Merge all values of a node's child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm completely new to XSLT. In a large text corpus, I should merge all values of a node's child nodes:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <Informations>
        <Information lang="de" type="a">
            <title>Product</title>
            <Holder>Big Company</Holder>
            <Code>0101010</Code>
            <content>
                <div>
                    <p class="s4" id="section1">
                        <span class="s2">
                            <span>This is Text</span>
                        </span>
                        <sup class="s3">
                            <span>®</span>
                        </sup>
                    </p>
                    <p class="s6">
                        <span class="s5">
                            <span>Sometimes sentences ar</span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="s5">
                            <span>e split by tags</span>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                 </div>
             </content>
         </Information>
    <Informations>
```

The resulting document should look like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <Informations>
        <Information lang="de" type="a">
            <title>Product</title>
            <Holder>Big Company</Holder>
            <Code>0101010</Code>
            <content>
                <div>
                    <p>This is Text®</p>
                    <p>Sometimes sentences are split by tags</p>
                </div>
            </content>
        </Information>
    <Informations>
```

So basically, I have to copy the whole structure but merge all values of the p-tags' subnodes while getting rid of these subnodes. I'd be very greatful for some help. Thanks!

**Update**: Without preserving the whitespaces within the p nodes to be stripped, some words become directly conjoined to each other. E.g. in an environment such as in

```
        <p class="s8">
           <span class="s9">
              <span>Inform your </span>
           </span>
           <span class="s9">
              <span>dentist.</span>
           </span>
        </p>
```

the resulting text is: Inform yourdentist
Therefore I tried to preserve the trailing whitespaces in the style sheet:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:preserve-space elements="p"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select='normalize-space()'/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

However, words split in two span tags are not correctly conjoined now. E.g from the example above: "sentences ar e split". I tried to find a way to mask/convert all trailing whitespaces first, but it didn't work out..

**Update 2**: The wrong results arise from sections such as the following where empty tags (resp. containing a whitespace only) separate two words. Is there a possibility not to process them as empty tags?

```
        <p class="s3">
           <span class="s4">
              <span>Read</span>
           </span>
           <span class="s4">
              <span> </span>
           </span>
           <span class="s4">
              <span>the</span>
           </span>
           <span class="s4">
              <span> information </span>
           </span>
           <span class="s4">
              <span>sheet</span>
           </span>
           <span class="s4">
              <span> </span>
           </span>
           <span class="s4">
              <span>carefully</span>
           </span>
        </p>
```

**Update 3**: With the 2-step-transformation almost everythings works except for the fact that the  tags are ignored, so that

```
        <p class="s3">
           <span class="s4">
              <span>Read</span>
           </span>
           <span class="s4">
              <span> </span>
           </span>
           <span class="s4">
              <span>the</span>
           </span>
           <span class="s4">
              <span> information </span>
           </span>
           <span class="s4">
              <span>sheet</span>
           </span>
           <span class="s4">
              <span> </span>
           </span>
           <span class="s4">
              <span>carefully</span>
           </span>
           <span class="s4">
              </br>
           </span>
           <span class="s3">
              <span>This is important</span>
        </p>
```

Becomes "Read the information sheet carefullyThis is important." I tried to convert every /br to a line break, but that doesn't work. Is it possible to somehow convert each /br into a closing /p-Tag and open a new p tag at the same time? Or converting it to

```
<span> </span>
```

might work as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO! We are not a code writing service and expect that you show your own effort and ask for help about that.

Comment: **Hint:** *The string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in document order.* https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#element-nodes

Comment: Re your edit: your result cannot be reproduced - see: http://xsltransform.net/naZXpXv

Comment: True, the faulty output only occurs when words are split by tags containing only a whitespace: http://xsltransform.net/naZXpXv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Re your Update 2

The given input:

**XML**

```
<p class="s3">
   <span class="s4">
      <span>Read</span>
   </span>
   <span class="s4">
      <span> </span>
   </span>
   <span class="s4">
      <span>the</span>
   </span>
   <span class="s4">
      <span> information </span>
   </span>
   <span class="s4">
      <span>sheet</span>
   </span>
   <span class="s4">
      <span> </span>
   </span>
   <span class="s4">
      <span>carefully</span>
   </span>
</p>
```

poses conflicting requirements:

- on the one hand, you want to strip the whitespace nodes surrounding
  the inner `span` elements;
- on the other hand, you want to preserve the spaces contained within the inner `span` elements.

Since both the inner and the outer elements are named the same, this is quite impossible.

What you could do is pre-process the input XML using the following stylesheet:

**1st XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span[not(@class)]">
    <new-span>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </new-span>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to produce:

**2nd XML**

```
<p class="s3">
   <span class="s4">
      <new-span>Read</new-span>
   </span>
   <span class="s4">
      <new-span> </new-span>
   </span>
   <span class="s4">
      <new-span>the</new-span>
   </span>
   <span class="s4">
      <new-span> information </new-span>
   </span>
   <span class="s4">
      <new-span>sheet</new-span>
   </span>
   <span class="s4">
      <new-span> </new-span>
   </span>
   <span class="s4">
      <new-span>carefully</new-span>
   </span>
</p>
```

Then process the result with the next stylesheet:

**2nd XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:preserve-space elements="new-span"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select='.'/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to produce the final result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>Read the information sheet carefully</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script include a template for `p` tags:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But this is not all. At the beginning of your script add:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

Otherwise the output will contain extra spaces and `/n` chars.

The script must include also an *identity template*.

### Edit

My whole script is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Do not use `preserve-space` for `p` tags as the output will include unnecessary spaces.

In the template for `p` you can change `.` to `normalize-space()` to:

- remove initial and trailing spaces (from the whole joined text),
- change multipe "middle" spaces to one space.

But note that if your source is:

```
<span>Inform your</span
<span>dentist</span>
```

then you will get `Inform yourdentist` (there is not space between *your*
and *dentist*, neither in source nor in the result).

Comment: Thanks! I included the identity template but got some problems with whitespaces now (see update above). Do you have any idea how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

First note that in XSLT, the string value of an element is the concatenation of the text nodes it contains. This generally works very well for mixed content (text in which some words or phrases are marked up by wrapping them in an element).

However, with mixed content it's important to be careful with whitespace. The paragraphs

```
<p>
  <b>Mind</b> 
  <b>the</b> 
  <b>gap!</b>
</p>
```

and

```
<p><b>Mind</b><b>the</b><b>gap!</b></p>
```

are different. But many XML editing tools make it very easy to insert or drop whitespace between tags in mixed content, and once you've done this, your information is corrupted for ever: you have lost the distinction between these two paragraphs. Your sample shows mixed content that has been indented, and that's pretty catastrophic: you have lost the distinction between significant and insignificant whitespace, and unless you can go back to an earlier version of the data, you can never recover this.